# Problems implementing groupedLayerControl plugin in R Leaflet

Tags: r, plugins, leaflet

I'm trying to implement the plugin extension , groupedLayerControl, for leaflet maps. You can see below the code I'm working with (currently not working). I'm trying to put the overlayers in different group categories. I'm new to javascript so I really can't identify what I'm doing wrong. The code does not give me the groups' layers in the map. Can someone help me out?

```
registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
    map
  }


Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22)
Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3)
Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2)
Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0)



leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = "Alpha") %>%
  registerPlugin(groupedLayerControlPlugin) %>%
  
  onRender("function(el, x) {
        var baseLayers = {
            'Alpha': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Alpha'),
        };

        var groupedOverlays = {
            'Group 1': {
                'Value1': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Value1'),
            },
            'Group 2': {
                'Value2': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Value2'),

            }
        };

        var Options = {
          groupCheckboxes: true
        };

        console.log(L.control.groupedLayers);
        L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, Options).addTo(this);
    }") %>%
  
  addCircles(lat=Lat, lng=Lon, 
             radius = Value1*1000, group = "Value1") %>%
    
  addCircles(lat=Lat, lng=Lon,
             radius = Value2*10000, group = "Value1")
```

Comment: Why are you tagging the question a "Java" question? How is Java involved?

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question , but thought I'd add a complete working example using your data. You only had one issue in the provided example, which was that you needed at least one `group = "Value2"` argument for one of the `leaflet::addCircles()`. Both of the `addCircles()` in your example show  `group = "Value1"`).

In the below code, I've also added an additional base layer to demonstrate base layer grouping in addition to the groupedlayercontrol of overlays.

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22)
Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3)
Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2)
Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0)

urlf <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/gh-pages/dist/%s'
download.file(sprintf(urlf,'leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.js'), 'C:/Temp/L.Control.groupedlayer.js', mode="wb")
download.file(sprintf(urlf,'leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css'), 'C:/Temp/L.Control.groupedlayer.css', mode="wb")

groupedLayerControlPlugin <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  name = 'ctrlGrouped',
  version = "1.0.0",
  src = c(file = normalizePath('C:/Temp')),
  script = "L.Control.groupedlayer.js",
  stylesheet = "L.Control.groupedlayer.css"
)

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Watercolor", group = "Beta") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = "Alpha") %>%

  registerPlugin(groupedLayerControlPlugin) %>%

  
  onRender("function(el, x) {
         var groups = {
            Value1: this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Value1'),                   
            Value2: this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Value2')  
            };
        var baseLayers = {
            'Alpha': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Alpha'),
            'Beta': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Beta')
        };

        var groupedOverlays = {
            'all value groups': {
           'Value 1' : groups.Value1,                                      
           'Value 2' : groups.Value2}
        };

        var Options = {
          groupCheckboxes: true
        };

        console.log(L.control.groupedLayers);
        L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, Options).addTo(this);
    }")  %>% addCircles(lat=Lat, lng=Lon, 
                     radius = Value1*1000, group = "Value1") %>%
  
  addCircles(lat=Lat, lng=Lon,
             radius = Value2*10000, group = "Value2")
```